# Xamarin.Forms iOS app wrapping with Intune App Wrapping Tool: 'The app's Frameworks directory could not be signed' error

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, intune, intunemam

I created a new Xamarin.Forms application (It is empty app. I created it only test Intune app wrap). I signed this iOS app and created an IPA. Then, I tried to wrap this signed IPA using the Intune App Wrapping Tool by following the steps in the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-wrapper-prepare-ios#general-prerequisites-for-the-app-wrapping-tool

The command I used to wrap it is as follows:

`sudo /Volumes/IntuneMAMAppPackager/IntuneMAMPackager/Contents/MacOS/IntuneMAMPackager -i /Users/pcname/Desktop/IntuneAppWrap/TestApp.ipa -o /Users/pcname/Desktop/IntuneAppWrap/TestApp_Wrapped.ipa -p /Users/pcname/Desktop/IntuneAppWrap/testapp.mobileprovision -c “my certificate SHA-1” -v true`

As a result, I am getting the following error:

> The app's Frameworks directory could not be signed. This may be because it contains files whose format was unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.
> Cause of the error to be provided for investigation:Error Domain=IntuneAppPackager Code=1 "/usr/bin/codesign exited with an error." UserInfo={Error Description=SignFrameworksError, NSLocalizedDescription=/usr/bin/codesign exited with an error.}

What could be the reason for this, and what am I doing wrong?